# Replace all regex matches in a row, conditionally and from a starting point

Tags: regex

A little cumbersome description, but here's an example. I would like to turn `s`,

`s="something in the beginning #and something here at the end"`

into `t`,

`t="something in the beginning #and_something_here_at_the_end"`.

That is, use a regex to replace all spaces with `_`, but ONLY if I'm at a row that contains the `#` character, and only in the sentence after it.

My problems is that I can use regex to look for 
`s/(.*)#(.*) (.*)/\1#\2_\3/`, but then I can't do this for an arbitrary number of spaces... and on the other hand, I can't use simply `s/ /_/g`, because it'll replace all the spaces before the `#` sign and also in rows without this sign at all (that I would like to keep as they are).

This is a toy example, I would like to know how to do this with regex in the general case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [\G](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) anchor, that matches at the position of the last position and [\K](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) to keep out things matched before. This leads to

```
(?:^[^\#]*#|(?!^)\G)[^\s]*\K(\s)
```

and replace it with `_`

- `^[^\#]*#` starts with the anchor for the start of the string, then matches any non-# and a #
- `(?!^)\G` matches the position of the last match. there is a lookahead to ensure we are not at the start of the string (first run \G is initialized at the start)

  - `[^\s]*\K` matches any non whitespaces and then forgets the match until here
- (\s) matches a whitespace

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oU4hN4/1